# Visual C++ (C++/CLI) Forward Declaration with Derivative Classes?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, forward-declaration

Okay, so I'm running into trouble with Forward Declarations in Visual Studios C++ (C++/CLI).
The code is as follows:

A.h

```
#include "B.h"

#ifdef B_H
#pragma once

public ref class A : public base_class  //base_class is public, memory managed 
{
    B^ b;
}

#endif
```

B.h

```
#define B_H

#pragma once

ref class A;

ref class B 
{
    A^ a;
}

#include "A.h"
```

The #ifdef/#pragma guards should keep be keeping a *.h from being read twice, and forcing b.h to be read first, and from the compiler output I'm pretty sure they are. (I'm not even sure the #ifdef/#define is needed with the #pragma once and #include placement)

But, the complier complains of a *path/a.h: error C2011: 'class' type redefinition.
See file path/B.h*

Should I be doing something with the forward declaration of A because it's a derivative class in the actual class definition, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two changes needed:

1. Add semicolons after the closing brace of the class definitions.
2. In A.h, move the `#pragma once` to be the very first line in the file. It's getting screwed up by having this inside the `#ifdef` block.

Also, note that a simpler way to do this would be to not have either header file include the other, and use forward declarations in both files:

A.h:

```
#pragma once
ref class B;
public ref class A : public base_class  //base_class is public, memory managed 
{
    B^ b;
};
```

B.h

```
#pragma once
ref class A;
ref class B 
{
    A^ a;
};
```

Comment: By shifting the #pragma once outside the #ifdef A is not defined if A.h is preprocessed first.

Also, I need to use the methods of the references in the .cpp files so I need #include somewhere in the .h files, but using the second method and adding the #include at the bottom of the .h's works! 

Thanks!

Comment: To solve that, I'd recommend that you remove that #include from the bottom of the header file, and simply #include both A.h and B.h from your .cpp file.

Comment: Isn't putting #include in .cpp files bad practice? (not that everything's not all mashed together after preprocessing anyway)

Comment: Not that I know of. If your project is using preprocessed headers, it's usual to put #includes from outside your project into `stdafx.h` (such as `#include<windows.h>`), but for header files inside the project, it's normal to have a half-dozen #includes at the top of every .cpp file, or more.